# How to get the full URL in Express?

Tags: node.js, url, express

Let's say my sample URL is

> http://example.com/one/two

and I say I have the following route

```
app.get('/one/two', function (req, res) {
    var url = req.url;
}
```

The value of `url` will be `/one/two`.

How do I get the **full URL** in Express?
For example, in the case above, I would like to receive `http://example.com/one/two`.

Comment: FYI you can inspect the request object and look through but I am a hypocrite and found it on here.

Comment: I have created: [Request: Introduce a `req.completeURL()` method · Issue #4697 · expressjs/express](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4697) for this.

Answer (score 987, accepted):

1. The protocol is available as `req.protocol`. [docs here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.protocol)

   1. Before express 3.0, the protocol you can assume to be `http` unless you see that `req.get('X-Forwarded-Protocol')` is set and has the value `https`, in which case you know that's your protocol
2. The host comes from `req.get('host')` as Gopal has indicated
3. Hopefully you don't need a non-standard port in your URLs, but if you did need to know it you'd have it in your application state because it's whatever you passed to `app.listen` at server startup time. However, in the case of local development on a non-standard port, Chrome seems to include the port in the host header so `req.get('host')` returns `localhost:3000`, for example. So at least for the cases of a production site on a standard port and browsing directly to your express app (without reverse proxy), the `host` header seems to do the right thing regarding the port in the URL.
4. The path comes from `req.originalUrl` (thanks @pgrassant). Note this DOES include the query string. [docs here on req.url and req.originalUrl](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.originalUrl). Depending on what you intend to do with the URL, `originalUrl` may or may not be the correct value as compared to `req.url`.

Combine those all together to reconstruct the absolute URL.

```
  var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
```

Comment: Thanks - I ended up running into where some servers were on a different port than 80.

Comment: Can't all the headers be manipulated? So you can't depend on it to be correct?

Comment: @dave a client can send whatever headers it wants (as well as whatever URL, port, random non-HTTP garbage), however, at some point bogus or inaccurate headers will simply cause the protocol to fail. For example, in a virtual host environment, an incorrect "host" header will display a completely different web site. In the case of X-Forwarded-Protocol, that is usually not send by the actual client (browser) but by the reverse proxy (nginx/varnish/apache/whatever) that is serving HTTPS in front of your application.

Comment: You missed the port section, you can get it by using: app.get('port')

Comment: @diosney bullet 3 addresses the port. AFAIK `app.get("port")` will return undefined unless you have explicitly done an `app.set("port")`. There's no built-in functionality there. It's just a convenience key/value store.

Comment: The browser sends those in the "Authorization" request header in this format. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side You should be able to find npm modules to decode the simple format it uses.

Comment: when you use XHR.open(method,url,true,user,pass) is actually sends them in the url 'http://user:pass@host.com:8080/p/a/t/h?query=string#hash'

Comment: Is original URL just the same as req.url as long as req.url hasn't been changed?

Comment: Does req.url actually change across the middleware? I'm creating a middleware and I need access to the original URL, but the middleware is framework independent right now.

Comment: The `host` parameter in the request headers can be spoofed. There's a possible "host header attack" if using the `res.host` this way. In the Django framework they have an 'allowed hosts' variable that is used to prevent such attack. I use a configuration variable that is my `root_url` which can be added to the `req.url` for completion. About the attack: http://www.skeletonscribe.net/2013/05/practical-http-host-header-attacks.html

Comment: For browsers other than Chrome you can also use `req.socket.localPort` or `req.socket.remotePort` depending on what you need exactly. But if there are proxies involved I am not sure what will happen.

Comment: If you want to add `req.originalUrl` without parameters, simply do `req.originalUrl.split("?").shift()`. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32118818/2037431

Comment: Thanks it helps me. Before i do not know how to use window object and after reading this answer i know to use it either in response or request object

Comment: What about proxied requests?

Comment: Express 4.x strips the port from `req.host`, `req.hostname`, and `req.get('host')`. Undocumented, but works, is to access `req.headers.host` directly.

Comment: Please note with this recommendation that relying on both req.host and req.get('host') can introduce security issues

Comment: The "Host" header is not supported in HTTP 2. You might want to consider using `req.host` or `req.hostname` and `server.address().port` for compatibility.

Answer (score 175):

Instead of concatenating the things together on your own, you could instead use [the node.js API for URLs](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html) and pass `URL.format()` the informations from express.

Example:

```
var url = require('url');

function fullUrl(req) {
  return url.format({
    protocol: req.protocol,
    host: req.get('host'),
    pathname: req.originalUrl
  });
}
```

Comment: In my case the `req.get('host')` returns only the *hostname* part, not the port. Don't know why, but now I gather the port number from the settings, and use the `hostname` field, instead of `host`.

Comment: Instead of `pathname`, I think you mean `path`. Which includes search/querystring

Comment: This doesn't work for URL's that have a query string.

Comment: I find this URL object useful, so if you could have a query string in your URL you could set it up by combining it with the answer from Peter Lyons, eg: 

`const url = new URL(req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl)`

Comment: `url.format` is now deprecated.

Comment: yes, meanwhile you'd use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL - feel free to update the answer / give a new answer.

Comment: This, as most answers here (if not all of them) is wrong since it ignores the port.

Answer (score 50):

**In 2022**

The above answers are working fine but are not preferred by the Documentation because `url.parse` is now `legacy` so I suggest you to use `new URL()` function if you want to get more control over `url`.

### Express Way

You can get `Full URL` from the below code.

```
`${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}${req.originalUrl}`
```

Example URL: http://localhost:5000/a/b/c?d=true&e=true#f=false

**Fixed Properties** ( you will get the same results in all routes )

```js
req.protocol: http
req.hostname: localhost
req.get('Host'): localhost:5000
req.originalUrl: /a/b/c?d=true&e=true
req.query: { d: 'true', e: 'true' }
```

**Not Fixed Properties** ( will change in every route because it controlled by express itself )

Route: `/`

```
req.baseUrl: <blank>
req.url: /a/b/c?d=true&e=true
req.path: /a/b/c
```

Route `/a`

```
req.baseUrl: /a
req.url: /b/c?d=true&e=true
req.path: /b/c
```

Documentation: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.baseUrl

### URL Package Way

In the `URL` function, you will get the same results in every route so properties are **always fixed**.

**Properties**

[image]

```js
const url = new URL(`${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}${req.originalUrl}`);
console.log(url)
```

You will get the results like the below. I changed the order of the properties as per the image so it can match the image flow.

```
URL {
  href: 'http://localhost:5000/a/b/c?d=true&e=true',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: '5000',
  host: 'localhost:5000',
  origin: 'http://localhost:5000',
  pathname: '/a/b/c',
  search: '?d=true&e=true',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams { 'd' => 'true', 'e' => 'true' },
  hash: ''
}
```

**Note**: `Hash` can not send to the server because it treats as `Fragment` in the server but you will get that in the client-side means browser.

Documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_new_url_input_base

Comment: This answer is not correct in 2021. There is no obvious way to get the "port" part of the url. In the example it claims that ```req.get("host")``` will include the port but besides "host" being deprecated, this is just not the case.

Comment: `get()` is used for getting headers of the request and in the request, you have the `host` header so it simply calls the request header and gets the port and it's very safe to use and nothing is depereacted here

Answer (score 42):

I found it a bit of a PITA to get the requested url. I can't believe there's not an easier way in express. Should just be req.requested_url

But here's how I set it:

```
var port = req.app.settings.port || cfg.port;
res.locals.requested_url = req.protocol + '://' + req.host  + ( port == 80 || port == 443 ? '' : ':'+port ) + req.path;
```

Comment: port variable has to be defined?

Comment: Does `req.port` exist? It is not in the Express documentation?

Comment: My bad. I assumed you would know what port you're serving off of and set that prior. I'll update the example again. You can also get it with `req.app.settings.port`

Comment: when req.protocol is empty, does it mean http?

Comment: This one is not including the query. It is not complete. The accepted answer is better.

Comment: This is just wrong. The port does not necessarily match the listening port since there can be proxies, load balancers, etc in front of the express service.

Answer (score 25):

Here is a great way to add a function you can call on the req object to get the url

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.getUrl = function() {
      return req.protocol + "://" + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
    }
    return next();
  });
```

Now you have a function you can call on demand if you need it.

Comment: This doesn't include the user:password that you can get in a full url 'http://user:pass@host.com:8080/p/a/t/h?query=string#hash'

Comment: @CodeUniquely true, but since that convention has been deprecated for over a decade now, hopefully no one is actually building userinfo specs into their APIs

Comment: That doesn't depricate.

Answer (score 18):

Using [url.format](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_format_urlobj):

```
var url = require('url');
```

This support all protocols and include port number. If you don't have a query string in your originalUrl you can use this cleaner solution:

```
var requrl = url.format({
    protocol: req.protocol,
    host: req.get('host'),
    pathname: req.originalUrl,
});
```

If you have a query string:

```
var urlobj = url.parse(req.originalUrl);
urlobj.protocol = req.protocol;
urlobj.host = req.get('host');
var requrl = url.format(urlobj);
```

Answer (score 13):

Use this,

```
var url = req.headers.host + '/' + req.url;
```

Comment: Use var url = req.headers.host + req.url

Answer (score 13):

make req.host/req.hostname effective must have two condition when [Express behind proxies](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html):

1. `app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');` in app.js
2. `X-Forwarded-Host` header must specified by you own in webserver. eg. apache, nginx

**nginx**:

```
server {
    listen myhost:80;
    server_name  myhost;
    location / {
        root /path/to/myapp/public;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://myapp:8080;
    }
}
```

**apache**:

```
<VirtualHost myhost:80>
    ServerName myhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/myapp/public
    ProxyPass / http://myapp:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://myapp:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: the example from: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache/

Comment: yep, nobody told that, if you have no correct configuration in apache or nginx, you will get `127.0.0.1` from `req.get('host')`

Answer (score 11):

Just the code below was enough for me!

```js
const baseUrl = `${request.protocol}://${request.headers.host}`;
// http://127.0.0.1:3333
```

Answer (score 11):

You can get the full url from req of express.

```
function fetchPages(req, res, next) {

    let fullUrl = req.headers.host + req.originalUrl;
    console.log("full url ==> ",fullUrl);
}
```

Comment: this works for nuxtjs also!

Answer (score 8):

You need to construct it using `req.headers.host + req.url`.  Of course if you are hosting in a different port and such you get the idea ;-)

Comment: That gets me everything but the protocol...is there anything that can tell me that?

Comment: To get the protocol use: `req.protocol`

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest using originalUrl instead of URL:

```
var url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
```

See the description of originalUrl here:
http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.originalUrl

In our system, we do something like this, so originalUrl is important to us:

```
  foo = express();
  express().use('/foo', foo);
  foo.use(require('/foo/blah_controller'));
```

blah_controller looks like this:

```
  controller = express();
  module.exports = controller;
  controller.get('/bar/:barparam', function(req, res) { /* handler code */ });
```

So our URLs have the format:

```
www.example.com/foo/bar/:barparam
```

Hence, we need req.originalUrl in the bar controller get handler.

Answer (score 8):

```
var full_address = req.protocol + "://" + req.headers.host + req.originalUrl;
```

or

```
var full_address = req.protocol + "://" + req.headers.host + req.baseUrl;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can combine `req.protocol`, `req.hostname`, and `req.originalUrl`. Note `req.hostname` rather than `req.host` or `req.get("host")` which works but is harder to read.

```javascript
const completeUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.hostname}${req.originalUrl}`;
```

Answer (score 6):

My code looks like this,

`params['host_url'] = req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host + req.url;`

Answer (score 6):

I use the node package 'url' (npm install url)

What it does is when you call

```
url.parse(req.url, true, true)
```

it will give you the possibility to retrieve all or parts of the url. More info here: https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-url

I used it in the following way to get whatever comes after the / in http://www.example.com/ to use as a variable and pull up a particular profile (kind of like facebook: http://www.facebook.com/username)

```
    var url = require('url');
    var urlParts = url.parse(req.url, true, true);
    var pathname = urlParts.pathname;
    var username = pathname.slice(1);
```

Though for this to work, you have to create your route this way in your server.js file:

```
self.routes['/:username'] = require('./routes/users');
```

And set your route file this way:

```
router.get('/:username', function(req, res) {
 //here comes the url parsing code
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this function in the route like this

```
app.get('/one/two', function (req, res) {
    const url = getFullUrl(req);
}

/**
 * Gets the self full URL from the request
 * 
 * @param {object} req Request
 * @returns {string} URL
 */
const getFullUrl = (req) => `${req.protocol}://${req.headers.host}${req.originalUrl}`;
```

`req.protocol` will give you http or https,
`req.headers.host` will give you the full host name like www.google.com,
`req.originalUrl` will give the rest `pathName`(in your case `/one/two`)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for this information. This is incredibly annoying.

Add this to your code and you'll never have to think about it again:

```
var app = express();

app.all("*", function (req, res, next) {  // runs on ALL requests
    req.fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl
        next()
})
```

You can do or set other things there as well, such as log to console.

Answer (score 1):

```
async function (request, response, next) {
  const url = request.rawHeaders[9] + request.originalUrl;
  //or
  const url = request.headers.host + request.originalUrl;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

Usually I rely on these 2 in the code, depends on the server and proxy exists:

`req.socket.remoteAddress`

`req.headers.referer`

Comment: Why this have too low? This is just the answer req.headers.referer

Answer (score -3):

```
const fullUrl = `${protocol}://${host}:${port}${url}`
      
    const responseString = `Full URL is: ${fullUrl}`;                       
    res.send(responseString);  
})
```