# Allow API call from a specific mobile app

Tags: node.js, express, azure-web-app-service

By using Node and Express, can I allow only HTTP REST calling from a specific mobile app?

For security reason, I want to achieve these:

```
 1. Allow only specific IP range. Since both of the app is hosted using Azure website.
 2. Allow only connection from specific mobile app.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CORS or JSONP

In CORS

For example, to allow http://mozilla.com to access the resource, you can specify:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mozilla.com

Answer (score 0):

You can check HTTP Headers to get the client ips, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849687/express-js-how-to-get-remote-client-address)
Check the ip with your IP list and only return if it is success.