# Express ip filter for specific routes?

Tags: node.js, express, ip, access-control

Is it possible to apply different ip filters to different routes?

For example, I want only people from 123.123.123.123 can access my server's `/test` route, and only people from 124.124.124.124 can access my server's `/` route.

I know that [express-ipfilter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ipfilter) can restrict site access by IP Address. But it cannot apply the filter to specific routes.

I also know that adding `app.use(ipfilter(ips, {}));` in the middle of the routes can apply filter only to the routes below:

```
var express = require('express'),
    ipfilter = require('express-ipfilter').IpFilter;

var ips = ['::ffff:127.0.0.1'];
var app = express();

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.send('test');
});

app.use(ipfilter(ips, {})); // the ipfilter only applies to the routes below

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

But I want different filters for different routes.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible. You could do something like:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    var trustedIps = ['123.123.123.123'];
    var requestIP = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    if(trustedIps.indexOf(requestIP) >= 0) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // handle unallowed ip
    }
})
```

You may need to make sure that `requestIP` is correctly formatted though.

Comment: +1 could even write up a middleware function for a clean implementation if you need to implement it on several routes.

Comment: For those using Google App Engine or another server running NGINX, this answer about getting the IP address with `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` is relevant in combination with the method above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10849772/1024735

Answer (score 5):

> **Warning**: package `express-ipfilter` is now deprecated.

You can chain middlewares (and ipFilter is a middleware).  There are 2 ways to do this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    ipfilter = require('express-ipfilter').IpFilter;

var ips = ['::ffff:127.0.0.1'];
var testers = ['1.2.3.4'];
var app = express();

app.get('/test', ipfilter(testers, {mode: 'allow'}), function(req, res) {
    res.send('test');
});


// the ipfilter only applies to the routes below  
app.get('/', ipfilter(ips, {mode: 'allow'}), function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Or qualify the use of the middleware:

```
var express = require('express'),
    ipfilter = require('express-ipfilter').IpFilter;

var ips = ['::ffff:127.0.0.1'];
var testers = ['1.2.3.4'];
var app = express();

app.use('/test', ipfilter(testers, {})); // the ipfilter only applies to the routes below    

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.send('test');
});

app.use('/', ipfilter(ips, {})); // the ipfilter only applies to the routes below

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Are you sure express-ipfilter is now deprecated? express-ipfilter was last published 2 months ago, whereas express-ip-filter (with hyphen) was last published 3 years ago

Answer (score 0):

In your main file where u defined app,

```
app.use('/test',require('./whereever-my-route-is-located-where /test routes '));
app.use('/',require('./wherever-my-this-routes-are-located'))
```

in your route file .

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();
//Ip verification for all requests : for whereever-my-route-is-located-where /test routes 
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    //verify Ip Logic
});
//this will be called for every route u define in that file, if it fails.
```