# express js get user's remote ipaddress getting ::ffff:127.0.0.1

Tags: node.js, express

I am having trouble detecting user's ipaddress. I tried using variations but these are the results.

```
req.headers['x-forwarded-for']: undefined
req.connection.remoteAddress: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
req.socket.remoteAddress: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
req.ip: ::ffff:127.0.0.1

clientIp: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Well are you trying on the same computer ? (That shoud explain the `127.0.0.1` you get)

Comment: If you're behind a proxy, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10849772/3196753.  There are some security warnings buried in the comments.

Comment: I am using chrome, the nodejs/expressjs is on an aws server