# Api url is being called automatically

Tags: node.js, express

I am having a strange issue. The api url is being called number of times automatically. I have absolutely no clue about this.

How to check the caller IP or how can I trace who is calling. The api has been built using node express and mongo.

A particular function inside model is being called.

Any clue is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849687/express-js-how-to-get-remote-client-address

Comment: Thanks.Did the way it suggested but it's still showing old console.log('some text') after changing the text and the ip isn't showing.