# Get client IP address of a request instead of Cloudflare's IP address

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, cloudflare

Cloudflare changes the IP addresses of incomming requests because Cloudflare is a middleware between my website and the Internet, a proxy.

How should I **get the initial IP address of the request**, not Cloudflare its IP address. I heard about the `mod_cloudflare` but does this plugin only updates the IP address in my logs (?) And I didn't find a version for Nginx.

Comment: try this: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170706-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-Nginx-

Comment: Are you connecting through a socket?

Comment: @roryrjb Already tried that, didn't work for me. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cloudflare sets the [`CF-Connecting-IP` and the `X-Forwarded-For` headers](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170706-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-Nginx-) on every request

You can simply get the IP from their special header:

```
let ip = req.headers['cf-connecting-ip']
```

If you expect requests outside of Cloudflare, you can get these IPs the following way:

```
let otherIp = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
```

Though, be wary, that other Proxies (like Nginx) will also set the `x-forwarded-for` header.

Comment: Works for third party website requests, I also added my own website to the website and this is the IP that's returned from the `req.cf_ip`:  2a02:1810:9410:7b00:8829:fc7f:b81f:10f, any idea what this is?

Comment: An IPv6 address

Comment: No, you can't transform them to IPv4 addresses, it's a different Version of the internet protocol, get used to them ;-)

Comment: If I use `req.body.remoteAddress` then it's a ipv4 address. Isn't there a way to check if the response is ipv4 or ipv6 in Nodejs?

Comment: You can check if it contains a dot using `String#includes`, if it does, its an IPv4 address

Comment: Seems legit. Thank you for the help.

Comment: For some odd reason I don't receive any requests. I made a post to give some more information about what's going on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52034699/nodejs-only-options-request-is-send-to-the-rest-api-post-or-get-doesnt-follo

Comment: Wouldn't this expose you to spoofing from connections that are not coming through Cloudflare? Hence Cloudflare recommends limiting to connections from their IPs: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170786-Restoring-original-visitor-IPs

Comment: @ewall sure, if you only expect connections through Cloudlfare you should not look for other IPs. I have edited the answer accordingly, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using express? If so you can use the [cloudflare-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudflare-express) middleware package to retrieve the IP addresses you need.

```
var cloudflare = require('cloudflare-express');
...
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
...
app.use(cloudflare.restore({update_on_start:true}));
```

Then the user's original address appears on `req` objects as `cf_ip`.

You may also, if your express app is behind a typical nginx reverse proxy, use [express's `trust proxy` setting](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html).

For example:

```
    app.set( 'trust proxy', 'loopback' ); //trust localhost reverse proxy
```

Other request-processing frameworks most likely have their own packages to do similar things.

Comment: Works for third party website requests, I also added my own website to the website and this is the IP that's returned from the `req.cf_ip`:  2a02:1810:9410:7b00:8829:fc7f:b81f:10f, any idea what this is?

Comment: @Michiel ipv6 ip, i hate those with a passion