# NodeJS - only OPTIONS request is send to the REST API, POST or GET doesn't follow (Cloudflare)

Tags: node.js, rest, cors, ip, cloudflare

When my website calls the REST api (code below) then only the `OPTIONS` request goes through, the `POST` or `GET` request doesn't follow. The `OPTIONS` request successfully passes the CORS whitelist. The `POST` or `GET` request isn't logged, it's also not blocked by the whitelist. The weird thing is that the Google Recaptcha request works, all the third websites does, except for mine. The api is running on the same domain as the website, just another port.

My website is using Cloudflare, Cloudflare constantly changes the IP addresses of the incomming requests. My website his ip address is ipv6 after it went through the cloudflare proxy. The website his ip is listed as an ipv6 address in the whitelist array.

```
const whitelist = ["*all the ip addresses"];

var corsOptions = {
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback('Not allowed by CORS');
        }
    }
};

const app = express();

mongoose.connect(*mongodb credentials*);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.headers.origin = req.headers['cf-connecting-ip'] || req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
    next();
});

app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: '*/*', limit: '2mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '2mb', extended: true}));

app.use(*routing*);

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

app.use is only for registering middlewares.
you need to specify a routing for each method you are using. app.get, app.put, app.delete and etc.
you can also use app.all for all methods
You can find more information here : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Well you can actually can use `app.use()` to do that. It looks like this `app.use('/api/articles, articleRoutes`. `articleRoutes` points to all the routes. If I comment out the cors configuration then everything works fine. Except that the IP whitelist doesn't work.