# How to get user ip in nodejs model ? and update in my table column ip_address

Tags: node.js, express

I want to write function in models to get user ip  , and want to store in user table has column name ip_address in node js. (using express, mysql)

```
  User.prototype.userip= function(req, res)
  {
    // here need access to IP address here
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express.js: how to get remote client address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849687/express-js-how-to-get-remote-client-address)

Answer (score 6):

```
req.connection.remoteAddress
```

Try this

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use `os`
[API from `os` to get IPv4](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_networkinterfaces)

```
var os = require('os');
var networkInterfaces = os.networkInterfaces();

console.log( networkInterfaces );
```

[API from npm `ip` to get IPv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip)

```
var ip = require("ip");
console.dir ( ip.address() );
```