# Get Client Public IP

Tags: javascript, ip, public

How can I get client public IP without using any API call or external Node Modules?

I already tried req.ip and req.ips but nothing helped me

Comment: Could you provide more detail please? Your questions is currently of a very low quality, for one, you've provided no source code.

Comment: Your question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849687/express-js-how-to-get-remote-client-address

Comment: yaa thanks @SifatHaque

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question, 
Finally, I found a solution to get client Ip without using any modules or any API call

```
(req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
    req.connection.remoteAddress ||
    req.socket.remoteAddress ||
    req.connection.socket.remoteAddress).split(",")[0];
```

Above code will return the clients public IP.