# Obtain Web Visitor IP Address in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I attempt to use express to obtain visitor ip address using: console.log(req.ip);
I connected to ngrok tunnel on a different device and ISP to test load the page.
But I am getting the result as ::1 instead of an IP address.
Anyone can advise what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
const clientIpAddress = String(req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.connection.remoteAddress);
```

Ref: [Express.js: how to get remote client address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849687/express-js-how-to-get-remote-client-address)

Comment: I would recommend against posting on clearly duplicate question as it only promotes people to post duplicates without any research effort..