# Save user IP adress to DB using express/mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I want to save users IP address to mongoDB using mongoose model file for user.
Any has any suggestions how can I do that?

Users module file schema:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 4
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 4
    },
    IP: {
        type: String
    }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849687/express-js-how-to-get-remote-client-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using express this should be fairly simple:

```
app.post('/your-route', async ( req, res ) => {
  await YourModel.save({ 
         IP: req.connection.remoteAddress, 
         // other fields
        });
});
```

If you're behind a proxy or need a more sophisticated approach you can consider using a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip to determine the IP-address.

Comment: when I run it, I get " IP:"::1"  in DB, as far as I understand it means 127.0.0.1, right? Will it work properly ( will I get proper local IP?  ) when I run it on other network?

Comment: Yes, since you're using IPv6 you'll see ::1 if you perform the request from your localhost.