# How to get IP address from request context nestjs?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I want to build simple authentication using IP addresses, some IP address that I whitelisted can access the API. But I got a problem when I use `request.ip` it only output `::1` which is not a real IP address.

How to get the user IP Address in nestjs? Here are my code right now

```
import {
  Injectable,
  CanActivate,
  ExecutionContext,
  Logger,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const allowedIp: Array<string> = ['129.2.2.2', '129.2.2.2'];
    if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
      const ip = request.connection.remoteAddress;
      Logger.log(ip, 'ACCESSED IP ADDRESS');
      if (allowedIp.includes(ip)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:

Turns out that `::1` are valid address for 'localhost' but when I deploy it on server and access the app from browser its log `::ffff:127.0.0.1` not my real IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned on Discord, you can use the header `X-Forwarded-For` as you're using `nginx` as a reverse proxy. The reason for getting `::1` is because that's the IP that the proxy is running on (i.e. `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`)

Comment: Is there a way to handle this for both proxied and non-proxied environments?
I've looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849687/express-js-how-to-get-remote-client-address) but typescript complains about `string | string[]` when I try to remove the IPv6 mask (`::ffff:x.x.x.x`). Using a type guard was mentioned, but I'm sure there's an elegant, straightforward solution I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

```
async tokenByUserData(@Context() context, @Args('token') token: string) {
    const {
      req: { user, ip },
    } = context;
    console.log({ ip });
    const { userId } = user || {};
    enter code here
```

here u can get ip and ::1 for localhost`enter code here`