# node.js with express how to remove the query string from the url

Tags: node.js, express, query-string

I have a button that is performing a get to my page and adding a filter to the query string. My code applies that filter to the grid but the user can remove/edit that filter.  Since they can see what filter was applied in the grid, I would like to remove the `?filter=blah` from the query string when the page is displayed.

It might be confusing if on the page and the URL says `?filter=columnA` which is correct initially, but the user removes that filter and applies a new one on `columnB` but the query string still says `?filter-columnA`. The grid can handle changing filters without needing a post back.

How can I do that?  And if you cannot remove/update a query string, is it possible to parse it and then just redirect to the main page without the query string?  Once I have the filter saved to var filter, I no longer need it in the query string.

here is the code that displays the page:

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
    var filter = req.query.filter;
    if (filter === null || filter === "") {
        filter = "n/a";
    }
    
    res.render("somepage.jade", {
            locals: {
                title: "somepage",
                filter: filter
            }
    });

};
```

Answer (score 69):

Use `url.parse()` to get the components of your address, which is `req.url`. The url without the query string is stored in the `pathname` property.

Use express' `redirect` to send the new page address.

```
const url = require('url'); // built-in utility
res.redirect(url.parse(req.url).pathname);
```

**Node** docs for [`url`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url).

Comment: Use req.originalUrl instead of req.url to work inside of nested router

Comment: A more modern way would be to use `new URL(req.originalUrl).pathname` instead of `url.parse(req.url).pathname`. This lets you avoid loading the url module (`const url = require('url');` line).

Comment: @JakubKukul this is not correct for Node: you are still supposed to require the `url` module in Node.

Comment: For a bit more context: in Node.js "originalUrl" only has the path part of the URL and the URL constructor treates this as an invalid URL; so you *can't* use that simple construction in Node.js-land.

Answer (score 34):

Don't use a module for doing something like that:

```
res.redirect( req.originalUrl.split("?").shift() );
```

Comment: "Don't use a module for doing something like that." Why? [`url.parse`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) is a core module since `0.1.25` and very suitable for this task.

Comment: @MarttiLaine cause native javascript can delete a string after a eventual given char. (Thought it may have some caveats for complex urls or with hashHistory)

Answer (score 23):

Express 4.x+ answer:
`res.redirect(req.path)`

Comment: `res.redirect(req.baseUrl)`

Comment: req.baseUrl is undefined, req.path works as intended.

Comment: In some cases (e.g. when in middleware) you might actually need to combine `req.baseUrl` and `req.path`. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 10):

### Generic Node.js solution

```js
> new URL('https://example.com/admin/new?foo=bar').pathname;
'/admin/new'
```

If you also want to include the origin:

```js
> const url = new URL('https://example.com/admin/new?foo=bar')
> url.search = '';
> url.toString() 
'https://example.com/admin/new'
```

### Express.js solution

Other answers include various combinations of using `req.url` / `req.originalUrl` / `req.path` / `req.baseUrl`. Which one to use depends on the context. These properties behave differently if you're in the `app.METHOD` function or if you're accessing them from inside a middleware or a nested router.

**Summary:**

- Using `req.originalUrl` should be the most versatile, but you need to parse the pathname yourself (see above).
- Using `req.path` is the most straightforward, but you have to make sure you're not in a middleware/nested router.

##### When you're inside of the `app.METHOD` function:

```js
// GET 'http://example.com/admin/new?foo=bar'
app.get('/admin/new', (req, res) => {
    console.dir(req.originalUrl); // '/admin/new?foo=bar'
    console.dir(req.url); // '/admin/new?foo=bar
    console.dir(req.baseUrl); // ''
    console.dir(req.path); // '/admin/new'
    return res.status(200).send('All engines running!');
});
```

##### When you're inside a middleware (or a nested router):

```js
// GET 'http://example.com/admin/new?foo=bar'
app.use('/admin', (req, res, next) => {
    console.dir(req.originalUrl); // '/admin/new?foo=bar'
    console.dir(req.url); // '/new?foo=bar'
    console.dir(req.baseUrl); // '/admin'
    console.dir(req.path); // '/new'
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 8):

**Use `req.path`**

If your endpoint is `http://<your-domain>.com/hello/there?name=john`...

then `req.path` = `/hello/there`

---

Documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.path

Answer (score 6):

```
// load built-in utilities for URL resolution and parsing
var url = require('url');

function removeQueryString(url){

  // split url into distinct parts
  // (full list: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost)
  var obj = url.parse(url);

  // remove the querystring
  obj.search = obj.query = "";

  // reassemble the url
  return url.format(obj);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The full url is stored in `req.url` in your case, use node.js's [url.parse()](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) to pull out the parts. Take the path and send a Location header using `res.set()` to redirect to URL without the query string.

```
var url = require('url');
res.set('Location', url.parse(req.url).pathname);
```

Comment: I tried that...it still has the query string in it...maybe I am not calling the right thing to "redirect" it.  My code is as follows:  exports.show = function(req, res) {
    var filter = req.query.filter;
    if (filter === null || filter === "") {
        filter = "n/a";
    }

    res.set('Location',url.parse(req.url).pathname);

    res.render('somepage.jade', {
            locals: {
                title: 'somepage',
                filter: filter
            }
    });

};

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid reload the page by forcing a redirect, I added the following to the `<head>` section of my .ejs file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uri = window.location.toString();
    if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
        var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
        window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
    }
</script>
```

Source: http://atodorov.org/blog/2013/01/28/remove-query-string-with-javascript-and-html5/

Comment: Did you try reloading? If not, the reload doesn't work as there are no query parameters now to get the data about.

Answer (score 1):

use this method to remove specific query parameter from URL.

```js
/**
     * remove query parameters from actual url
     * @param {*} params paramerters to be remove, e.g ['foo', 'bar'] 
     * @param {*} url actual url 
     */
    function removeQueryParam(parameters = [], url) {
        try {
            var urlParts = url.split('?');
            var params = new URLSearchParams(urlParts[1]);
            parameters.forEach(param => {
                params.delete(param);
            })
            return urlParts[0] + '?' + params.toString();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return url;
        }
    }

    console.log(removeQueryParam(["foo"], "/foo?foo=foo&bar=bar"));
```

Above example will return **/foo?bar=bar**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the way that I approached it was by adding a script in the  section. However, in order to avoid inconsistencies when I was moving either backward or forward I needed to add an **onbeforeunload** event listener. The benefit of that approach is that it avoids the redirection.

```
    // Stores the original url in the local storage
    window.localStorage.setItem('specifiedKey', window.location.href);

    // Cleans the query parameter of a string and replace it in the history API
    const cleanUrl = location.href.match(/^.+(?=\?)/g);
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, (cleanUrl ? cleanUrl[0] : location.href));

    // the history is updated before the window reloads
    window.onbeforeunload = () => {
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.localStorage.getItem('specifiedKey'));
        }
```

The only issue that I imagine is browser incompatibility, with the JavaScript engine not being able to support a regex look-behind operator. This can be easily fixed using .split('?')[0]