# Express.JS get url path without any additional parameters

Tags: express, url, parameters, path, request

Is there any straightforward way to get URL path segment without any additional data (url parameters, css '#', etc.)

for example:
full URL: `http://example.com/panel/list`
path segment I want to get: `/panel/list`

full URL: `http://example.com/panel/list?user=joe`
path segment I want to get: `/panel/list`

full URL: `http://example.com/panel/list#header`
path segment I want to get: `/panel/list`

And any other combination of data that is not path segment of my URL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js with express how to remove the query string from the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166898/node-js-with-express-how-to-remove-the-query-string-from-the-url)

Answer (score 9):

I think you can use `req.baseUrl + req.path`.

And for full URL use [req.originalUrl](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl).

Comment: but if I type /admin I get /admin/ instead

Comment: Edit, I just used replace to trim last trailing slash (req.baseUrl + req.path).replace(/\/$/, "")

Answer (score 1):

For full url without any parameters, you can use `req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.baseUrl + req.path;`