# Strip specific query parameters in express

Tags: node.js, express, url

I am having some difficulty in stripping specific query parameters from a request in express. The issue is that in the normal flow, the user would fetch a Bearer Token from a third party which would then be sent to my REST API with each request. The token is decoded and the id of the user is added to the request.

I would like to be able to attach the ID of the user as a query parameter while in development mode, so that I can test the API using something like cURL or Postman, without having to write some sort of script to fetch a token every time.

To that end, I created a separate middleware to be used in development that would take the ID from the querystring, strip it out, and redirect to the new URL. I modified [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19638803/4108556) to do so.

```
this.app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.query.id;
    req.user = { id };
    let basePath = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    const queryKeys = Object.keys(req.query);
    if(queryKeys.length === 0) return res.status(400).send('no id attached');
    if(queryKeys.length === 1 && queryKeys[0] === 'id') return next();
    basePath += '?';
    queryKeys.forEach(queryKey => {
       if(basePath[basePath.length -1] !== '?') basePath += '&';
       if(queryKey !== 'id') basePath += `${queryKey}=${req.query[queryKey]}`
    });
    return res.redirect(basePath);
})
```

This function works fine if I test it using just the ID parameter, (say: `http://localhost:5000/api/?id=someid`) but if I add a second parameter(say: `http://localhost:5000/api/?id=someid&skip=1`), I get a 404 with the message `/ is not a recognized path.`. From `console.log()` statements I can see that in the second example, `res.redirect()` is being called with `/?skip=1`, as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do as it seems that you're redirecting to the same URL without the `id` query parameter, which would return a `400` error.

In any case, please take a look at this code snippet that correctly removes the `id` query parameter and does the redirection.

```
const url = require('url');
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // return early if the id query parameter is not present
  if (!req.query.id) {
    return res.status(400).send('No id attached.');
  }

  // rebuild URL by removing the id query parameter
  const baseUrl = url.format({
    protocol: req.protocol,
    host: req.get('host'),
  });
  const myUrl = new url.URL(req.originalUrl, baseUrl);
  myUrl.searchParams.delete('id');
  const cleanUrl = `${myUrl.pathname}${myUrl.search}`;

  // redirecting to the URL without the id parameter will return a 400
  return res.redirect(cleanUrl);
});
```

You can easily adapt the code by using the `cleanUrl` variable so that, instead of redirecting to it, you could take some different action.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I can see what you mean now about the 400, for some reason I assumed that I would skip the middleware on redirect. But your solution, while far more concise than mine, still has the same result. 404. The issue actually lies elsewhere, replacing the entire middleware with `res.redirect('/');` also fails with 404, but a direct call to `next()` passes it on to the '/' route handler. I suppose I could just replace the name of the param with some random char sequence that can be left in the request and is unlikely to interfere with the application in the future.

Comment: My answer was based on the information you provided. I can't reproduce the `404` you describe without having access to more information.