# get auth portion of url with express.js

Tags: node.js, api, express

I'm building out an API using express.js

(its my first time doing this)

I want to authenticate requests by using the standard auth portion of the url. I want requests to come in as https:// {public-key}:{private-key}@host:port/path

I can't find the auth portion of the url anywhere. req.url is just /path

I found this [How to get the full url in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183291/how-to-get-the-full-url-in-express-js) which said to do the following:

```
req.protocol + "://" + req.get('host') + req.url
```

But that returns only https:// host:port/path

Any help would be great.

As a side note, if this isn't the standard way to authenticate APIs please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `express.basicAuth()` [middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#basicAuth) to get the username and password sent with the URL.

```
app.get('/',
  express.basicAuth(function(username, password){
      console.log(username);
      console.log(password);
    return (true);
  }), 
  function(req,res){
    ...
  });
```

Or like the conventional `app.use` fashion

```
app.use(express.basicAuth(function(user, pass){
  return 'tj' == user & 'wahoo' == pass;
}));
```