# Referring actual url during REST Call

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.post('/sQ', function (req, res){
            var url = req.get('host') + ' '  +req.url;
    console.log('url is ' +url);
            res.send(url);
});
```

The above will print `www.example.com/sQ`. In place of `/sQ` the actual URL may be different.

If the above is a REST call instead of the actual url. How can you refer the actual url?

For eg.
Angular can make following call from any url.

```
$http({method: 'get', url: '/sQ'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);      
    }
  });
```

Comment: You'll need to clarify precisely what you mean by "actual URL". If you want to reconstruct a complete URL you could put into an HTML email, for example, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10185427/266795

Comment: the url which is in the browser.

Comment: @PeterLyons yes i went thru that question. `var url = req.get('host') + ' '  +req.url;` code comes from there only.