# express.js request.url is always /

Tags: node.js, express

I just created my first app with node.js and express. And I only want to print out current url, so I add these lines:

```
app.use('/test', function(request, response){
    console.log('current url is '+request.url);
    response.end();
})
```

Now when I run on browser at localhost:3000/test in will print me: `current url is /`  Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: I think you might also have another console.log, which prints the 'current url is /'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try for this:

```
var Url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
```

[Reference in StackOverflow: How to get full URL in Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183291/how-to-get-the-full-url-in-express-js)

Answer (score 7):

i had the same issue and the solution was so obvious...

I had a "express rule" like:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/')
})
```

And that redirect me automaticly to "/" route so it doesn't work...

In your case, I think the problem comes from your keywork "use" used with express.
Try this:

```
app.get('/test', function(request, response){
    console.log('current url is '+request.url);
    response.end();
})
```

Comment: using get instead of use resolved this issue for me. app.use is in fact mounting middleware rather than routing requests.

Comment: The second part of this answer should be the accepted answer.