# Custom URL in Node Express

Tags: node.js, express, path

I need to save the full path as a string for further processing, i.e.

localhost:3000/abc/xyz/etc

would give me:

"/abc/xyz/etc"

I tried

```
app.get('/.+:path', function(req, res) {
   console.log('path:'+req.params[0]);
});
```

But it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10185427/5812121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.get('/:path*', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.params.path + req.params[0]);
});
```

Comment: hint: req.url is the actual path

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what's the route and what's the params but this is a good starting point:

```
app.get('/abc/:path', function(req, res) {
   console.log('path:'+req.params.path);
});
```

If you call `localhost:3000/abc/xyz` You will get `path:xyz`