# Get full route url expressJs

Tags: node.js, express

I want to get URL of route in express js.

```
http://localhost:9310/api/arsys/v1/entry/SimpleForm5/?fields=Request ID,Assigned To,Status,Submitter,Create Date&q=Status=New&offset=5&sort=Create Date.desc
```

I want only `http://localhost:9310/api/arsys/v1/entry/SimpleForm5/`

I tried `const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host + req.url;` which gives `http://localhost:9310/SimpleForm5/?fields=Request%20ID,Assigned%20To,Status,Submitter,Create%20Date&q=Status=New&offset=5&sort=Create%20Date.desc`

But it does not give `/api/arsys/v1/entry/`. Also I does not want query params in output.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the full url in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183291/how-to-get-the-full-url-in-express)

Comment: Is it `req.path` that you want?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the url without queryParams however with host, originalUrl, You can go that way:

```
const urlWithoutQueryParams = req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host + url.parse(req.originalUrl).pathname;
```

For example, consider that code:

```
router.route('/arsys/v1/entry/SimpleForm5/')
  .get(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      console.log(req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host + url.parse(req.originalUrl).pathname)
      return res.status(200).send({ message: "OK" });
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).send({ message: "Failure" });
    }
  });

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(8080, () => {
  log.info('app started')
})
```

And when You send `GET` to:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/arsys/v1/entry/SimpleForm5/?fields=Request ID,Assigned To,Status,Submitter,Create Date&q=Status=New&offset=5&sort=Create Date.desc
```

Result is:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/arsys/v1/entry/SimpleForm5/
```