# Node JS request get original url

Tags: node.js

I'm sending GET requests like this in Node JS in a loop

```
    request({
        url : 'https://somelink.com',
        method: 'GET'
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Since the response is async, is it possible to get the original request URL in the response?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure what you're trying to ask but see the following link and see if it works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/10185427/6352772.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more so that we can understand what you actually want?

Comment: umm well I'm just trying to get the original request URL after successfully making the GET request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the original request href in the response.request object, like so:

```
const request = require("request");
request({
    url : 'https://google.com',
    method: 'GET'
},
function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log("Original url:", response.request.uri.href);
        console.log("Original uri object:", response.request.uri);
    }
});
```

You can access more information in the request.uri object, for example:

```
console.log("Original uri:", response.request.uri);
```

This will give you some more useful information like port, path, host etc.

Comment: I added this but I get: "Caught exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined"

Comment: Oh, great thank you for trying my answer! Is is possible that the error object is populated? Did you try with a valid url, e.g. 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2' ?

Comment: I replaced the URL with 'https://google.com' and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the answer, you might try it now. Thanks!