# Express's req.url sometimes contains a full URL (including protocol+host) rather than just the path

Tags: node.js, express

I was recently surprised to find that `req.url` (inheritied from [node's http module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url)) and `req.originalUrl` (a copy of `req.url` that is preserved from rewriting by middleware, for example) can return an absolute URL rather than a path.

This is because `message.url` in node's http module is simply the URL of the `GET` request, and [apparently](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) (if I'm readying right) a `GET` request can have an absolute URL and still be valid. (Edit: yes, [MDN confirms my understanding here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#:%7E:text=absolute%20form).)

So is it true that req.url and req.originalUrl are simply exact copies of the `GET` URL? If so, I'm really surprised that every answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183291/how-to-get-the-full-url-in-express), including ones with hundreds of upvotes say that you should get the full URL like so:

```js
req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl
```

Given that nearly 500k people have viewed that question without making a comment or answer, it seems like I must be missing something here. But then, reading [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3088#issuecomment-249439962), it seems that my interpretation is correct.

So I'm basically asking this question to confirm my understanding so I can write an answer/comment/edit on that linked question and hopefully help others avoid the problems that I had that result from using code like the above without handling the possibility of an absolute URL.

Comment: I had a similar problem with `req.get('host')`. Depending on the device it would return the full URL with protocol and not *just* the host

Comment: That's strange. I would have expected that express would reject requests with an invalid `Host` header. I guess they leave it up to the user, and just report exactly what they received. But it seems that the `GET` URL can actually be an absolute URL according to the spec, so in this case I'm just confused at the advice all over the internet to get the full URL by appending `req.url` to the protocol+host. Just need someone to confirm my understanding here so I can suggest some edits.