# Getting the request origin path through express

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have a node server which I connect to from my website.

For certain requests it needs to know the webpage the request came from.

When I use `req.headers.origin` I get [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) instead of [www.example.com/home/details](http://www.example.com/home/details)

Stuff like `req.path` `req.originalUrl` `req.host` I just get the API route for example [www.api.com/request](http://www.api.com/request) or /request

Comment: why not sending the current url from the browser when calling your node server ?

Comment: @RaphaelPICCOLO Just for convivence. That will be my solution if there is no way to do it from the back end

Comment: the wesite is on some domain, and you ajax directly on a node server on another domain, right ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will do the the trick:

```
var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
```

for more details please check complete answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183291/how-to-get-the-full-url-in-express?answertab=active#tab-top)