# How do I get a full request URL in a node js express function?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express 4.x. and I'm in a function like:

```
async function getIndexHTML(req, res) {

}
```

When I try to log error like this:

```
console.error(req);
```

It returns a `[Object]`

When I try to do this:

```
console.error(JSON.stringify(req));
```

It comes with another error

```
--> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
1|testprj  |     |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
1|testprj  |     --- property 'socket' closes the circle
1|testprj  |     at JSON.stringify ()
1|testprj  |     at getIndexHTML (/root/mytest/app.js:114:24)
```

I just want to know what exact URL the user is typing into the addressbar. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the full URL in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183291/how-to-get-the-full-url-in-express)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Full-URL from request like this:

```
const fullURL = `${req.protocol}://${req.hostname}${req.originalUrl}`
```